# Partitioning a graph into connected pairs and triplets

Tags: graphs, matching, partitions

We need to partition an undirected graph into connected subgraphs of size between $2$ and $k$, where $k$ is an integer.

When $k=2$, the problem is equivalent to the [perfect matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)) which is known to be solvable in polynomial time.

When $k=3$, the problem is similar to the [partition into triangles problem](http://profs.sci.univr.it/%7Errizzi/classes/Complexity/provette/Mirko/pt_fine.pdf), which is proved to be NP-complete by reduction from [3-dimensional perfect matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching#Notes). But there are two differences: first, we allow subgraphs of size 2; And second, we allow subgraphs of size 3 that contain only two edges (i.e. paths).

Is there a polynomial-time algorithm for this problem, assuming $k=3$? Assuming $k$ is fixed? Assuming $k$ is part of the input?

Comment: The conventional meaning of "a connected component" is "a connected subgraph that is not part of any larger connected subgraph". Do you mean  to "find a partition of the vertices of a graph so that each subgraph is connected with at most $k$ vertices"? Or you can redefine "connected component".

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be solved in the polynomial time for $k = 3$.

There is this paper by [Chen *et al.*](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1007/s10878-018-00372-z). The authors design an approximation algorithm for the *minimum $3$-path partition problem*. The *minimum $3$-path partition problem* is similar to your problem. It aims to partition the graph into minimum number of vertex disjoint paths each of size at most $3$. The only difference between this problem and your problem is that it allows a partition of size $1$, i.e., a singleton vertex.

In Section $2$, of the paper, authors design a polynomial time algorithm for computing *$3$-path partition with the least number of $1$-paths* ($1$-path means a singleton vertex). They further use this algorithm to design an approximation algorithm for the minimum $3$-path partition problem. However, this polynomial time algorithm gives a straightaway solution to your problem. If the algorithm returns a solution with non-zero number of $1$-paths, then the graph can not be partitioned into connected subgraphs of size between $2$ and $3$. And, if the algorithm returns a solution with no $1$-paths, then the graph can be partitioned into connected subgraphs of size between $2$ and $3$.

Comment: This is very surprising: if we allow paths of lengths $1,2,3$, or paths of length 3 only, then the problem is NP-hard; but if we allow paths of length $2,3$, the problem is in P?!

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Please note that in your problem, you asked for existence of a partitioning. However, the minimum path partition problem asks for a feasible partitioning with the minimum number of partitions. Indeed, in polynomial time you can find a feasible partitioning of paths of lengths $1$, $2$, and $3$; simply take all singleton partitions.

Comment: Ah, I see. So if we want to find a partition with a smallest number of paths of lengths 2,3, this will probably be NP-hard.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi yes. Right!